# Is it possible to disable coasting/inertia/momentum scrolling with scripts/other software?

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey, touchpad, scrolling

*Q: What do I mean by coasting/inertia/momentum/flick scrolling?*

A: It's the feature of trackpads where you can flick the trackpad up or down for a split second, and it keeps scrolling for a second or two AFTER you remove your fingers from the touchpad. It makes scrolling feel like "coasting" on a skateboard.

*NB: Coasting is NOT AT ALL the same as smooth scrolling.*

*Q: Why is this a problem?*

A: If you e.g. flick scroll a webpage and press ctrl+tab to swap to another webpage, the scroll animation continues, and results in your browser zooming in incredibly fast (ctrl+scroll=zoom in most applications).

---

Coasting IS a great feature, but only if it actually stops the animation immediately when you press another button.

That's why I am wondering if there is a way to make a script that cancels a scroll animation when you press any button (but not WHILE you're pressing a button, as you want to be able to scroll zoom, etc.)

Is it possible to "capture" the animation and cancel it, or is it buried deep within the Windows or trackpad drivers? After all these years there is zero hope of either Windows or Logitech actually fixing this problem. An Autohotkey script seems like the most promising avenue to fix this universally, but I have no idea how I would solve it with that.

Comment: Just touch the touchpad again with two fingers, it will stop scrolling on every browser I've ever used. I don't think a software solution to this problem makes sense.

Comment: @LayneBernardo I'm aware of this, but for one thing I'd rather not have to do that. Secondly, I might want to disable this behaviour completely.

Comment: Fair enough, unfortunately I don't know of any way to fix this in Windows. As you suggest, AHK sounds like the most promising solution.